# How can I stop the monitor continually running?

Tags: netlogo

The monitor (below) is continually running and generating a random list of output, even though there is no tick activity.

Questions:  Should it be continually running? Is there a way to monitor the list on the interface without the continual random output?

Code

```
to go
  crt 100 [fd random 14 + 1]
end

to-report report-red-turtles
  report [who] of turtles with [color = red]
end
```

To run:

On the interface, create a monitor report-red-turtles and a simple go button

Answer (score 1):

It is by design that ["Monitors automatically update several times per second"](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/interface.html#interfaceelements). It's a convenient design in most cases, but can also have some weird consequences (be careful never to have side effects in monitor code!)

What happens in your case is that

```
[who] of turtles with [color = red]
```

produces different output each time it runs: the list produced by [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) is always in random order.

To get around this fact, you have two options.

- Remove the randomness: `sort [who] of turtles with [color = red]`.
- Use a global variable (e.g. `red-turtles`), update it once per tick, and display that in your monitor.

It's a trade-off between simplicity and speed: the first option is simpler and cleaner, but more computationally expensive.